# Long continous sound with Gigabyte motherboard

Tags: windows-7, motherboard

I think I have a refurbish desktop computer since it has no labels or names on it. But the motherboard is a Gigabyte GA-H61M-S2PV. 
Now when  I switch on the computer, fan spins, lights on power/reset button comes on, everything looks normal but the screen displays "No Signal". During startup, a long continuous sound comes on after 3 beeps. Does not stop until i switch off.

RAM: 8Gb, Windows 7 Home Premium.

Anything else please let me know so i can provide.

Comment: I think 3 beeps is the RAM. Try re-seating the RAM sticks. What does the long sound sound like?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The 3 beeps  I understand is for the RAM but am puzzled about the long continuous noise. I tried re-seating the  RAM and switching between the 2 RAM slots but still nothing. Could it mean the slots are faulty?

Answer (score 0):

The beeps indicates the issue with RAM. If the RAM and Slots are not faulty then the third possibility is with the RAM IC. In some cases the RAM IC failure happens and consequently the RAM connected on the slots will not be recognized during POST. In such cases, it is recommended to replace the RAM IC.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. i found the problem. It was an internal speaker connected on the F_Panel on the motherboard. The + and - were not connected properly. Reconnected it and teh continous sound and beeps are gone.